# Swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

We now have an entire page of 2k users, followed by a page of 1k users, so hopefully are hitting the right success/size metrics. Traditionally Stack Exchange reward this with a cool swag giveaway. We really need to think about what this could be.

Obviously T-shirts are a no brainer. I haven't yet seen them in person, but @Jeff says they look grand - @Jin's design works.

So what else do we think we would like? One idea per answer, and vote for ones you like.

SE folks - let us know if we are on the right track here and what you have already planned :-)

Comment: Oh, bummer. I'll post a photo tomorrow night.

Comment: Hm, the site is still in the second beta phase and not considered mature by SE, until the top 40 tags have reached 200 questions each.

Comment: Although in looking at some of the other sites, that didn't seem to be the criterion used. Hopefully - as we only have 5 over 200 questions each

Comment: Obviously we should have [branded USB sticks](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/detecting-malware-infected-usb-drives)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shirt makes it on-stage at Shmoocon

[image: Screencap of shirt during talk]

Comment: +1000 - excellent!

Comment: When can the rest of us get a black version?

Comment: @Iszi It's actually navy

Comment: @JeffFerland Still a lot darker than the preview we've been given.

Comment: @Iszi If the shirt material is the same, you can expect something between the demo page and the color here. This batch of shirt was from DEFCON last year.

Comment: I'm jealous. I don't even have the shirt... it looks great on ya.

Answer (score 14):

Sec.SE branded lockpick credit cards, like Kevin Mitnick's famous one:

[image]

Comment: Love this idea.  I wonder how much those cost, anyway?

Comment: Found out.  If we wanted just one each, it seems the cost would be at least $280 for the first two pages of users.  That's $100 for a one-time film creation fee.  Then $1.80 per card, up to 500, minimum of 100.  After 500 cards, the cost drops to $1.60 per.  http://www.metalcards.com/metalcards/mcpricing.html

Answer (score 9):

T- Shirts with a big sec.se logo on the front or polo shirts with a small logo on the chest

Comment: And a target on the back?

Answer (score 7):

I'd like a Sec.SE branded mug. Not some generic Stack Exchange mug, one with my favorite site design.

Just to clarify, this may be too much for freebies; I'd pay for it.

Comment: I would also pay for a mug.

Comment: I, too would prefer a mug over a shirt, and would pay

Answer (score 5):

I'd love a baseball cap with logo and url on the back, like the popular EFF "SWAT" hat:  https://supporters.eff.org/shop/eff-swat-hat [image]

Comment: Hats are cool - http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/194/chrisf

Answer (score 4):

Rucksacks or swag sacks - not sure whether a laptop bag or a small single shoulder rucksack would be best here. Comments?

Answer (score 4):

Small, coloured enamel lapel pins with our logo - lapel pins are often a good conversation starter.

Comment: If you are not in management they might look pretentious.

Answer (score 3):

A teddy bear! I'll call him Tom, and feed him a honeypot called Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

Pens - either SE or Sec.SE branded would do

Answer (score 2):

Post it packs, or pads - with a small logo + URL these can be very effective to scribble notes on to give to others

Answer (score 1):

A Sec.SE branded keyring in the shape of a padlock, perhaps with one of those shopping trolley tokens.

Comment: I'm guessing "shopping trolley tokens" are a European thing?

Comment: could be @Iszi - see http://www.poundforlife.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

A pair of socks with a sec.SE logo would be awesome.